# Rails/Puma not reading environment variables when started as a Systemd service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I just deployed a Rails server in Production mode on Ubuntu 16.04. When I start the server from the command line as below, the server starts up and reads all the Environment varaiables.

```
bundle exec puma -e production -C /home/deploy/shared/config/puma.rb
```

But, when I switch to Systemd.service and have the server started from there, none of the Environment variables are read. I also tried reading and setting the environment variables in a before_configuration hook and that does not seem to help either.

**Setting Environment variables**

```
#config/initializers/set_environment_variables.rb
module SetEnvironmentVariables
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_configuration do
      env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'environment.yml').to_s

      if File.exists?(env_file)
        YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
          ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end # end YAML.load_file
      end # end if File.exists?
    end # end config.before_configuration
  end # end class
end # end module
```

**Puma systemd service file -**

```
#/etc/systemd/puma.service
[Unit]
Description=Puma Rails Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=deploy
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/current
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/shared/config/puma.rb'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec pumactl -S /home/deploy/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state stop'
TimeoutSec=15
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Rollbar initiliazer file -**

```
Rollbar.configure do |config|
  config.access_token = ENV['ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN']

  unless Rails.env.production?
    config.enabled = false
  end

  config.environment = ENV['ROLLBAR_ENV'] || Rails.env
end
```

**.bashrc**

```
#~/.bashrc
  export ROLLBAR_ACCESS_TOKEN="11111111111"
```

**Start puma.service - Log file**

```
deploy:~/current/log$ systemctl status puma.service
    ● puma.service - Puma Rails Server
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/puma.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-04-24 01:34:49 UTC; 3min 23s ago
      Process: 20593 ExecStop=/bin/bash -lc bundle exec pumactl -S /home/deploy/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 20948 (ruby)
        Tasks: 11
       Memory: 133.7M
          CPU: 5.849s
       CGroup: /system.slice/puma.service
               └─20948 puma 3.11.3 (unix:///home/deploy/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock) [20180423205334]                                                  
    lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

**Rollbar Error log**

```
[Rollbar] Scheduling item
[Rollbar] Sending item
[Rollbar] Got unexpected status code from Rollbar api: 400
[Rollbar] Response: {
  "err": 1,
  "message": "access token required"
}
[Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxexxx (only available if report was successful)
```

Comment: I believe that when you start server via systemd, it does not read your .bashrc file.


When you try to read variables it from the environment.yml file, can you see if the file is found there at all, and what values does it produce? Just print something in the loop to see that it reads the file and goes correctly through the values there

Comment: This is known behavior of SystemD and Upstart. https://askubuntu.com/questions/940679/pass-environment-variables-to-services-started-with-systemctl

Comment: I was hoping it would not be this system limitation, but thanks again for confirming. I will switch to storing values in a yaml/cache and reading at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I believe arnvald is right. ["systemd has an Environment directive which sets environment variables for executed processes. It takes a space-separated list of variable assignments"](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html) In that link you can see how to set variables to systemd units.

I readed in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/413408) that the current best practice is to set them in a file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but on your service, you can add variable manually or via a file.

```
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/file
Environment=MY_VAR=something
```

Note: `EnvironementFile` must load a file with the following pattern:

```
MY_VAR2=something
MY_VAR3=something_new
```

[Documentation](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with `puma` not loading `.env` file values at all... all i had to do was to define the values in the `puma.service` file using `Environment` for example:

`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/puma.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/rails_current_server

Environment="RAILS_ENV=production"
Environment="SERVER_TYPE=111"

ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/rails_current_server/config/puma.rb'
Restart=always
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Another alternative will be hardcoding the values of the env vars right in the `ExecStart` something like this: `ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'RAILS_ENV=production SERVER_TYPE=111  bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/rails_current_server/config/puma.rb'`